# Gradle-Git plugin Grgit type unknown

Tags: git, gradle, plugins, grgit

I am having issues with grgit plugin for gradle.

This is what I have in my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "3.0.0-beta.1"
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

apply from: 'path/to/my/otherFile.gradle
```

Now in my `otherFile.gradle` I would like to use Grgit like so:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

task cloneSomeRepo {
 doLast {
    def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: "$buildDir/my-repo", uri:          "https://mygitserver.com/repo/gitrepo.git")
    println grgit.describe()
  }
}
```

And in this file I am getting an error saying:

`Could not get unknown property 'Grgit' for root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

I am new to gradle, and I might not have understood how this should work, and any help Is very appreciated!

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious wrong with your code. Have you tried putting the same code directly in your `build.gradle` instead of in `otherfile.gradle`? There could be some issue with how it works in an `apply from`.

Comment: Actually, if I use it straight from the build.gradle all is good, just the actual clone operation can take some time, but that is not a real issue.

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the way that I am applying the other .gradle files into my build, since the import does not recognise any of the plugin classes that I'd like to use.

Comment: I know there are some things that don't work in `apply from` scripts, not sure if imports are one of them (I wouldn't have thought so).